# WSL 2, Ubuntu 22.04: apt-get update 403 authenticationrequired

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a fresh install of WSL 2 with Ubuntu 22.04 and I cannot perform an `sudo apt-get update` because of a 403 authentication required error (the full output is at the end).

EDIT0: I am running this VM on a work machine, but the same thing happens regardless of the VPN being active or not.

The VM does have access to the internet as it can ping google and archive.ubuntu.com without issue.

Maybe I need to make an account at the IP listed at the bottom of the output, but that seems rather odd for a variety of reasons, and I'm also not seeing where to supply those credentials to `apt-get`.

Here are the non-commented lines in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
```

Full `sudo apt-get update` output:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1395 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [510 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30.3 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [129 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted Translation-en [18.6 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [488 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [14.1 MB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [856 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en [175 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [11.4 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [953 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted Translation-en [154 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [532 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [788 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [144 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [144 kB]
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Err:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [14.1 MB]
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en [5652 kB]
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en
Err:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en
Err:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en
Err:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Ign:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main Translation-en
Fetched 14.8 MB in 36s (415 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

EDIT1: I managed to get `sudo apt-get update` to work while I had started the command while the VPN was active, turning the VPN off before the first 403 could be reached, and then the command finished normally. However, `sudo apt-get upgrade -y` doesn't seem to want to work the same way, which suggests that the VPN is to blame.

```sh
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apt apt-utils base-files bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu ca-certificates curl distro-info distro-info-data dpkg file gawk gcc-12-base git git-man iptables irqbalance
  libapt-pkg6.0 libbinutils libc-bin libc6 libcap2 libcap2-bin libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libgcc-s1 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libjson-c5 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnetplan0 libnss-systemd libpam-cap libpam-systemd libperl5.34 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libssh-4 libssl3
  libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtinfo6 libudev1 libunwind8 libx11-6 libx11-data libxtables12 locales motd-news-config ncurses-base ncurses-bin netplan.io openssh-client openssl perl perl-base perl-modules-5.34 python-apt-common
  python3-apport python3-apt python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm python3-problem-report python3-software-properties python3.10 python3.10-minimal snapd software-properties-common systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-standard ubuntu-wsl udev ufw vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd
105 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 60.4 MB/91.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 347 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.10 [1557 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.10 [78.0 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 iptables amd64 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libip6tc2 amd64 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libip4tc2 amd64 1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 dpkg amd64 1.21.1ubuntu2.2
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 apt amd64 2.4.10
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libncursesw6 amd64 6.3-2ubuntu0.1
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libtinfo6 amd64 6.3-2ubuntu0.1
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 irqbalance amd64 1.8.0-1ubuntu0.1
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 gawk amd64 1:5.1.0-1ubuntu0.1
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libk5crypto3 amd64 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libkrb5support0 amd64 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libkrb5-3 amd64 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libgssapi-krb5-2 amd64 1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2
  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
# Trimmed to meet message character length.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/iptables_1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/libip6tc2_1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/libip4tc2_1.8.7-1ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.21.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.4.10_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-data_2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-bin_2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-0_2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/irqbalance/irqbalance_1.8.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.19.2-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info-data/distro-info-data_0.52ubuntu0.4_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info/distro-info_1.1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libpam-cap_2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2-bin_2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c5_0.15-3%7eubuntu1.22.04.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/libnetplan0_0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.35-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt-common_2.4.0ubuntu2_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_2.4.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_29.4%7e22.04_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/xxd_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-tiny_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.12_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.12_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-minimal_1.481.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-dnsutils_9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-host_9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-libs_9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/file_5.41-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/libmagic1_5.41-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/libmagic-mgc_5.41-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-data_1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.5-0_2.5.16%2bdfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libssh/libssh-4_0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git-man_2.34.1-1ubuntu1.10_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git/git_2.34.1-1ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info/python3-distro-info_1.1ubuntu0.1_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_22.04.17_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-release-upgrader/python3-distupgrade_22.04.17_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-gdbm_3.10.8-1%7e22.04_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-standard_1.481.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ufw/ufw_0.36.1-4ubuntu0.1_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf0_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf-nobfd0_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libbinutils_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-common_2.38-4ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-common_2.5.16%2bdfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunwind/libunwind8_1.3.2-2build2.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.99.22.7_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.99.22.7_all.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/snapd/snapd_2.58%2b22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-wsl_1.481.1_amd64.deb  403  authenticationrequired [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the VPN is blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; turned out to be geo-discrimination: Toss up a USA VPN and you're golden.

EDIT: I realized you are actually getting Auth verbose error messages; your issue is likely different. Mine seemed to be false-positive 403 errs.

Still, try a VPN just to rule out geo!